# Баг Chrome или неправильный код?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

В документе на главной страницы содержится iframe (src="text.html").
В самом документе text.html я прописал скрипт, который убирает скороллинг, растягивая содержимое на всю высоту родительского экрана :

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe0').style.height = 
   document.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Все прекрасно в Мозилле и Опере, а вот в Google Chrome при обновлении страницы у этого фрейма ВНЕЗАПНО появляется скроллинг . Это баг Хрома? Или я чего-то не догоняю?

Comment: пример наjsfiddle или jsbin сделайте

Comment: Не разбираюсь, где мне в jsfiddle сам код iframe прописать?

Comment: сейчас покажу, через gist можно это сделать

Comment: Сейчас это превратится в онлайн-урок по jsfiddle )).  Вот, допустим, главная страница http://jsfiddle.net/995wP/ . Как мне прописать файл в src, где мне его создать и сохранить, я ни черта не пойму.

Comment: я ошибся, по какой-то причине gsfiddle дает возможность запрашивать страницы gist только через ajax, надо у них спросить почему.

Comment: Ну, что бы там ни было, Хром все равно показывает полосу прокрутки. И только ПОСЛЕ нажатия f5.

Comment: ну хотя-бы здесь выложите код подходящий к проблеме, а-то непонятно как повторить и что не нравится.

Comment: у меня в хроме при console.log(parent.document.getElementById('iframe0')) - выводится сначала 3 строки ошибок, а только потом сам ифрейм - возможно проблема в настройках безопасности кроссдоменных запросов в самом движке хрома
В последнее время хром ведет себя хуже ИЕ имхо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe src="..." onload="document.getElementById('content').style.height = 
        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 60 +"px">
```

где iframe - ссылка на объект iframe.

Код кроссбраузерный.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/WwS5L/

вот ваш пример, проблема у меня не повторяется. комменты почему-то отключены к задаче, пишу здесь.

Comment: Весьма сложно проследить это в jsfiddle, ведь там само окно разбито на 4  дива, т.е. див с результатом не является по-сути реальным окном windows.   К тому же в вашем примере после слова TEST я попробовал вставить текстовый контент, так после этого jsfiddle показал только пустой фрейм, даже без слова test.

Comment: И вообще я согласен, что это работает и должно работать, а вот Хром с этим несогласен. Будто при обновлении он перестает "замечать" скрипт в подключаемом фрейме

Comment: может надо onload скрипт выполнять  ?

Comment: скрипты прописаны в конце документа, перед последним body, т.е. перед скриптом дерево документа уже создано.